# How can I modify this jQuery plugin to have a method for updating the value of the counter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, methods, counter

I have been working with this jQuery counter plugin all day.... I finally got it implemented on my site and working. :) I however, cannot figure out a way to "update" the value of the timer with the plugin?

http://sophilabs.github.com/jquery-counter/

It doesn't seem to have a method for updating the actual number of the counter... I have tried writing some code that changed the data-stop attribute but that didn't work for me?!?

Basically I am looking for a way that I can use this plugin and then add an integer (say 5) to the counter with an onClick function.

SO ---> Click a button = Adds 5 to the counter!

Maybe I am just missing something here? or maybe the plugin must be modified with a new method for updating? not sure? Help appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code so we can locate the issue and solve accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current value of the counter, increment it and then apply the counter on it again, like this (button/link click event handler code below):

```
$("#incrementCounter").on('click', function(e) {
    var currentValStr = $(".counter-analog").text();
    var strLen = currentValStr.length;
    var currentValInt = parseInt(currentValStr, 10);
    var newString = '00000' + (currentValInt + 5);
    newString = newString.substring(newString.length - strLen, newString.length);
    $(".counter").counter('stop')
        .text(newString);
    $(".counter").counter();
});
```

You can check the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vishaldeep/rx5hf/3/)